# Django: Bootstrap Accordion not working on Regroup content

Tags: html, django, twitter-bootstrap-3

Django with Bootstrap 3

I am working on a dashboard view for an FAQ system. I have set up the articles to be grouped by section. The section names are the headers in a list-group that when clicked will expand another list-group containing all the articles related to that group.

The issue that I am having is that I would like to set up the collapse to work like an accordion. I have followed bootstrap 3’s guide to accomplish this but when I click a new section open none of the prior open sections collapse close. I have exhausted other guides but the code looks correct yet the accordion functionality is not working.

My code:

```
{% block content %}
<div class="iron-faq">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <h3>Sections</h3>
            <div class="list-group" id="accordion" aria-multiselectable="true">
            {% regroup articles by section as section_list %}


                {% for section in section_list %}
                    <a href="#section-{{ section.grouper.id }}" 
                        class="list-group-item list-header"
                        data-toggle="collapse" 
                        data-parent="#accordion" 
                        data-target="#section-{{ section.grouper.id  }}" 
                        aria-controls="section-{{ section.grouper.id }}">
                        <i class="fa fa-bars"></i> {{ section.grouper }} 
                        <span class="badge pull-right">{{ section.grouper.article_count }}</span>
                    </a>
                    <div class="panel-collapse collapse" id="section-{{ section.grouper.id }}">
                        {% for article in section.list %}
                            <a href="{{ article.get_absolute_url }}" class="list-group-item">
                                {{ article.title }}
                            </a>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </div>
                {% endfor %}
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <h3>Useful Articles</h3>
            <div class="list-group">
                <div class="favorites">
                {% for favorite in favorites %}
                    <a href="{{ favorite.get_absolute_url }}" class="list-group-item">
                        <h5 class="list-group-item-heading">{{ favorite.title }}</h5>
                        <p class="list-group-item-text">{{ favorite.section.name }}</p>
                    </a>
                {% endfor %}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to wrap each section with:

```
<div class="panel"></div>
```

So your html would look like the following:

```
{% block content %}
<div class="iron-faq">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <h3>Sections</h3>
            <div class="list-group" id="accordion" aria-multiselectable="true">
            {% regroup articles by section as section_list %}


                {% for section in section_list %}
                    <div class="panel">
                        <a href="#section-{{ section.grouper.id }}" 
                            class="list-group-item list-header"
                            data-toggle="collapse" 
                            data-parent="#accordion" 
                            data-target="#section-{{ section.grouper.id  }}" 
                            aria-controls="section-{{ section.grouper.id }}">
                            <i class="fa fa-bars"></i> {{ section.grouper }} 
                            <span class="badge pull-right">{{ section.grouper.article_count }}</span>
                        </a>
                        <div class="panel-collapse collapse" id="section-{{ section.grouper.id }}">
                            {% for article in section.list %}
                                <a href="{{ article.get_absolute_url }}" class="list-group-item">
                                    {{ article.title }}
                                </a>
                            {% endfor %}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                {% endfor %}
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <h3>Useful Articles</h3>
            <div class="list-group">
                <div class="favorites">
                {% for favorite in favorites %}
                    <a href="{{ favorite.get_absolute_url }}" class="list-group-item">
                        <h5 class="list-group-item-heading">{{ favorite.title }}</h5>
                        <p class="list-group-item-text">{{ favorite.section.name }}</p>
                    </a>
                {% endfor %}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: That worked like a charm. Thank you! I knew it was something small but just could not see it.